# Cannot find module 'slugid' in AWS lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, npm, aws-lambda

I have a lambda function which uses `const logger = require('../utils/logger').Logger;`, and that is the only component I was able to find anywhere that referenced `slugid` which is an npm module.

In the package.json file, I see `slugid` in both dependencies and dev-dependencies. Why is this not working in lambda? Any help appreciated.

The error message is as follows

```
"errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
"errorMessage": "Error: Cannot find module 'slugid'\nRequire stack:\n- /var/task/utils/logger.js\n- ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually if a lambda function depends on **external dependencies**, you have to bundle them yourself in your lambda function deployment package, as explained in aws [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-package.html#nodejs-package-dependencies):

> If your function depends on libraries other than the SDK for JavaScript, install them to a local directory with npm, and **include them in your deployment package**.

Comment: Thanks for replying! I tried doing `npm i` but then it complains about the lambda being too big (which makes sense because there's hundreds of other modules), if I remove other modules in the `node_modules` folder only leaving `slugid` then it gives the same error :/

Comment: @Kei If the only thing that depends on `slugid` is  `Logger`, can you remove `Logger` and use maybe some other logging package?

Comment: I found that it actually requires all the packages to be installed in node_modules, the only ones I can delete are those aws ones, that solved the problem (although this is more of a temporary fix) Thanks!